# ExecuteReader throw ORA-01840 but from sqlDeveloper works well

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am trying to execute an Oracle procedure from C#, but `ExecuteReader` is throwing an error:

> ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format.

If I execute the procedure with "data burned" in the WHERE clause, it works well, but not when the WHERE clause uses params.

This is OK:

```
rigrif.rig_dmov BETWEEN TO_DATE('03/04/2019', 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('03/04/2019','dd/MM/yyyy')
```

This is not OK:

```
rigrif.rig_dmov BETWEEN TO_DATE(p_date_from, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND TO_DATE(p_date_to,'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

//C# code

```
    public IEnumerable<StockMovements> GetGeneralStockVega(FilterStockValidator value)
    {
        List<StockMovements> list = new List<StockMovements>();

        try
        {
            Connection ObjCn = new Connection();
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ObjCn.getConnectionString()))
            {
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(StoredProcedures.sp_Get_GeneralStockVega, connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("p_filial", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2).Value = "18";
               command.Parameters.Add("p_date_from", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 22).Value = "03/04/2019";
                command.Parameters.Add("p_date_to", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 22).Value ="04/04/2019";
                command.Parameters.Add("p_respuesta", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                connection.Open();
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                StockMovements objStock = null;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    objStock = new StockMovements();
                    objStock.FechaMovimiento = reader["fecha_movimiento"].ToString();
                    objStock.Almacen = reader["almacen"].ToString();
                    objStock.CantidadVega = decimal.Parse(reader["cantidad"].ToString());
                    objStock.Documento = reader["documento"].ToString();
                    list.Add(objStock);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.RegError(ex, this.GetType());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Procedure code:

```
PROCEDURE get_vega_general_stock (
    p_date_from  IN  VARCHAR2,
    p_date_to    IN  VARCHAR2,
    p_filial     IN  VARCHAR2,
    p_respuesta  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN

  OPEN p_respuesta FOR
    SELECT 
        TRUNC(rigrif.rig_dmov)  AS fecha_movimiento,
        rigrif.rig_fili         AS almacen,
        rigrif.rig_mag          AS almacen_office,
        testrif.tst_doc         AS documento,      
        SUM(rigrif.rig_qta)     AS cantidad
    FROM 
        rigrif rigrif
    INNER JOIN detrif detrif
        ON rigrif.rig_det = detrif.det_prg
    INNER JOIN prodotti prodotti
        ON rigrif.rig_pro = prodotti.pro_cod
    INNER JOIN testrif testrif
        ON rigrif.rig_testrif = testrif.tst_prg
    WHERE 
        detrif.det_del = 'E'
    AND prodotti.pro_grp = 0
    AND rigrif.rig_fili = '18'
    AND rigrif.rig_dmov BETWEEN TO_DATE(p_date_from,  'dd/MM/yyyy' ) AND TO_DATE(p_date_to,'dd/MM/yyyy')
    GROUP BY
        TRUNC(rigrif.rig_dmov),
        rigrif.rig_fili,
        rigrif.rig_mag,
        testrif.tst_doc
    ORDER BY 
    1,2,3,4;
END get_vega_general_stock;
```

Comment: Use `date` as data type for a date, not `varchar2`, from the beginning.

Comment: What is the input value? It needs to be 10 characters long and a date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to write all table names twice (`rigrif rigrif` etc) and uppercase keywords are about as good an idea in PL/SQL as they are in C#.

Comment: the solution was send the parameters from c# in the same order of the procedure..